# How to position something on a certain point on a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

Right now I have the following code which adds the JLabel to the top center of the Panel, which I assume is the default

```
imageLabel = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon customer1 = new ImageIcon("src/view/images/crab.png");

        imageLabel.setIcon(customer1);
        storePanel.add(imageLabel);
        imageLabel.setBounds(20, 20, 50, 50);
```

setBounds obviously isn't putting it at 20,20....so how do you position something to a point within a Panel?

Answer (score 2):

Use the appropriate LayoutManager to place components in the panel.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

In your case you should be able to use a `FlowLayout` and set the horizontal and vertical gaps when you create it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html#FlowLayout(int,%20int,%20int)

Answer (score 2):

Seems your `storePanel` is `JPanel` and has default `FlowLayout` manager, because of your `setBounds(20, 20, 50, 50);` doesn't work. It will be work with null layout (`storePanel.setLayout(null);`).

But I recommend you to use [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Answer (score 1):

Although not recommended, you can do absolute positioning if you set your layout manager to `null`.

```
storePanel.setLayout(null);
// imageLabel initialization code
storePanel.add(imageLabel);
imageLabel.setBounds(20, 20, 50, 50);
```

[Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)

---

My advice is to use a Good IDE + UI Builder combo such as:

- [Netbeans GUI Builder](https://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html)
- [Eclipse WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/)
- [IntelliJ GUI Designer](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gui_builder.html)

Thease are WYSIWYG tools that can generate Swing code using flexible Layout Managers such as [Group Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) or [JGoodies Form Layout](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/).

A layout manager is a must if you want to design good UIs. They not only handle the size and positioning of components, but things such as redistributing / repositioning / resizing components on window resize (which is really hard to get right by hand). Also, those UI designers can hint you so that you stick to the guidelines and best practices in order to design high quality / cross-platform UI.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a bit of manual work you can add constraints to your label using a SpringLayout.  This allows you to position edges an exact distance from other edges, which by default also sorts the components size (By basically setting the edges a set distance apart when you lay it out)  I have demonstrated below with a textArea, but is could easily apply to your label as well.

```
public class SO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
    //Components
          JFrame frame = new JFrame();
          JPanel panel = new JPanel();
          panel.setSize(frame.getSize());
          JTextArea text = new JTextArea();         
    //Add components
          panel.add(text);
          frame.add(panel);         
    //Layout add & setup  
          SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
          panel.setLayout(layout);        
          layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, text, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, panel);
          layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, text, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel);
          layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, text, -10, SpringLayout.EAST, panel);        
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);        
    }
}
```

Comment: `frame.pack()` ??? instead of `frame.setSize(300, 300);`, thats way (how is designated)/for LayoutManager